# Why MUI Datagrid filter does not work if the filterModel is initialized using useState?

Tags: react-hooks, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

This looks very strange to me that when the filter model is initialized using **useState** hook, it does not work.

See the code here.

If I comment the statement on line 1 and uncomment statement on line 2, the filter does not work.

```
1     const filterModel = {items: [{columnField: 'descript', operatorValue: 'contains', value: descFilterModel}]};

2     //const [filterModel, setFilterModel] = useState({items: [{columnField: 'descript', operatorValue: 'contains', value: descFilterModel}]});
     
    
3   return (
        <DataGridPremium getRowId={(row) => row.qjobdefid}
          columns={columns}          
          filterModel={filterModel}          
          rows={rows}
          checkboxSelection={columns.length !== 0}
          disableSelectionOnClick
          loading={loading}
          rowHeight={48}
          scrollbarSize={10}
        />
    )
```

This is working with the above statement code where the line 2 statement is commented out.

[image]

See the filter stops working with this code (commented line 1 and removed comment from line 2)-

```
1     //const filterModel = {items: [{columnField: 'descript', operatorValue: 'contains', value: descFilterModel}]};

2     const [filterModel, setFilterModel] = useState({items: [{columnField: 'descript', operatorValue: 'contains', value: descFilterModel}]});
     
    
3   return (
        <DataGridPremium getRowId={(row) => row.qjobdefid}
          columns={columns}          
          filterModel={filterModel}          
          rows={rows}
          checkboxSelection={columns.length !== 0}
          disableSelectionOnClick
          loading={loading}
          rowHeight={48}
          scrollbarSize={10}
        />
    )
```

[image]